# subtract two fields from django admin

Tags: python, django

How do i subtract the two field values from django admin. here i gave my views and templtaes

**views.py**

```
for attendancesheet_info in attendance_sheet:
 attendancesheet_info.present_days= attendancesheet_info.working_days - attendancesheet_info.leave_days
```

**templates**

```
   </tr>
                  <tr>
                    {% for attendancesheet_info in attendance_sheet %}
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{ attendancesheet_info.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ attendancesheet_info.employeeid}}</td>
                    <td>{{ attendancesheet_info.employeename}}</td>
                    <td>{{ attendancesheet_info.working_days}}</td>
                    <td>{{ attendancesheet_info.leave_days}}</td>
                    <td>{{ attendancesheet_info.permissions}}</td>
                    <td>{{ attendancesheet_info.present_days}}</td>
                    </tr>
                     {% endfor %}


                  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate it in a class method in the model and reference that method in the admin as a read-only field in an edit view or list view in admin.py.

```
# this method goes into your model.
@property
def present_days(self):
    return self.working_days - self.leave_days
```

Your example template will also work. You don't need to do anything in the view to access `present_days`. The code in your question from views.py is not needed.

```
<td>{{ attendancesheet_info.present_days}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a model like `AttendanceSheet` defined in your `models.py`, you can create a `ModelAdmin` for this model in `admin.py` and specify the fields you want to appear on the admin page.

See [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options) related to this topic, especially the [`exclude` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude).